# Excel VBA to force numeric value into time format

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

There are two columns copied into a workbook from a Access database.

I want to ensure that the data is formatted correctly so I added this code:

```
'DateTime Column
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy hh:mm"

'Time Column
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
```

The datetime column formats correctly.
The time column is initially copied as a numeric equivalent (ie 0.595277777777778) instead of the time value (14:17).

Running the macro code does nothing to the visual display and it isn't until I hit F2 and enter on the cell that the format applies.

Is there a method (short of a loop) to force Excel to apply the formatting?

Comment: Are both Access columns using the Date data type?

Comment: @phoog - the time column is TEXT. The other is Date-Time.

Comment: @JohnM Are you able to use the Sheet.Refresh or Sheet.RefreshAll command?

Comment: @JohnM: that's the source of your problem.  The values are being pasted into the workbook as text values, rather than numeric, because the source column is a text column.  The best solution is of course to change the data type of the Access column.

Comment: @MattDonnan - The Sheet.Refresh/RefreshAll commands don't exist in my version of Excel-VBA.

Comment: @JohnM Apologies, I can't remember where it was I've seen it before, you may be able to use the Application.Calculate command instead, otherwise; ensure that you are setting your columns number format after pasting your data rather than before.

Comment: @phoog - Changing the database is possible but I also want the VBA code to handle 'bad' data.

Comment: @JohnM see my answer for a VBA solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy the column and paste as values (through a macro if needs be) then Excel should re-interpret the data type and the above should work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use VBA to accomplish the same effect as Steve Homer's answer by setting the range's value property to itself:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:B")
r.Value = r.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with out declare TMP as DATE:

```
TMP = CDate(Range("A1").Value) ' we suppose A1 value is 12:45:00
TMP = "" & TMP ' convert to char
TMP = Left(TMP, 5) ' extract the first 5 char
MsgBox TMP ' for displaying 12:45
```